# Bootstrap Nav Walker - Add Class to Child UL - multi-level menu

Tags: wordpress, twitter-bootstrap, drop-down-menu, menu, submenu

I'm working on a Wordpress site that someone else coded using Bootstrap. I added a submenu item to a submenu item, but it is appearing on top of it's parent, rather than under it.

I found code that would add a class to the submenu, but I need to add a class to the child of the submenu item.

Parent
  - A Submenu (child of main menu)
     --A1 Submenu (child of A)

I created a dropdown-submenu class in the css file, but I don't know how or where to add it to the wp_bootstrap_navwalker.php file. Code is below.

```
<?php

/**
 * Class Name: wp_bootstrap_navwalker
 * GitHub URI: https://github.com/twittem/wp-bootstrap-

navwalker
 * Description: A custom WordPress nav walker class to 

implement the Bootstrap 3 navigation style in a custom theme 

using the WordPress built in menu manager.
 * Version: 2.0.4
 * Author: Edward McIntyre - @twittem
 * License: GPL-2.0+
 * License URI: http://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-2.0.txt
 */

class wp_bootstrap_navwalker extends Walker_Nav_Menu {

    /**
     * @see Walker::start_lvl()
     * @since 3.0.0
     *
     * @param string $output Passed by reference. Used to 

append additional content.
     * @param int $depth Depth of page. Used for padding.
     */
    public function start_lvl( &$output, $depth = 0, $args = 

array() ) {
        $indent = str_repeat( "\t", $depth );
        $output .= "\n$indent<ul role=\"menu\" class=\" 

dropdown-menu\">\n";
    }

    /**
     * @see Walker::start_el()
     * @since 3.0.0
     *
     * @param string $output Passed by reference. Used to 

append additional content.
     * @param object $item Menu item data object.
     * @param int $depth Depth of menu item. Used for 

padding.
     * @param int $current_page Menu item ID.
     * @param object $args
     */
    public function start_el( &$output, $item, $depth = 0, 

$args = array(), $id = 0 ) {
        $indent = ( $depth ) ? str_repeat( "\t", $depth ) : 

'';

        /**
         * Dividers, Headers or Disabled
         * =============================
         * Determine whether the item is a Divider, Header, 

Disabled or regular
         * menu item. To prevent errors we use the 

strcasecmp() function to so a
         * comparison that is not case sensitive. The 

strcasecmp() function returns
         * a 0 if the strings are equal.
         */
        if ( strcasecmp( $item->attr_title, 'divider' ) == 0 

&& $depth === 1 ) {
            $output .= $indent . '<li role="presentation" 

class="divider">';
        } else if ( strcasecmp( $item->title, 'divider') == 0 

&& $depth === 1 ) {
            $output .= $indent . '<li role="presentation" 

class="divider">';
        } else if ( strcasecmp( $item->attr_title, 

'dropdown-header') == 0 && $depth === 1 ) {
            $output .= $indent . '<li role="presentation" 

class="dropdown-header">' . esc_attr( $item->title );
        } else if ( strcasecmp($item->attr_title, 'disabled' 

) == 0 ) {
            $output .= $indent . '<li role="presentation" 

class="disabled"><a href="#">' . esc_attr( $item->title ) . 

'</a>';
        } else {

            $class_names = $value = '';

            $classes = empty( $item->classes ) ? array() : 

(array) $item->classes;
            $classes[] = 'menu-item-' . $item->ID;

            $class_names = join( ' ', apply_filters( 

'nav_menu_css_class', array_filter( $classes ), $item, $args 

) );

            if ( $args->has_children )
                $class_names .= ' dropdown';

            if ( in_array( 'current-menu-item', $classes ) )
                $class_names .= ' active';

            $class_names = $class_names ? ' class="' . 

esc_attr( $class_names ) . '"' : '';

            $id = apply_filters( 'nav_menu_item_id', 'menu-

item-'. $item->ID, $item, $args );
            $id = $id ? ' id="' . esc_attr( $id ) . '"' : '';

            $output .= $indent . '<li' . $id . $value . 

$class_names .'>';

            $atts = array();
            $atts['title']  = ! empty( $item->title )   ? 

$item->title    : '';
            $atts['target'] = ! empty( $item->target )  ? 

$item->target   : '';
            $atts['rel']    = ! empty( $item->xfn )     

? $item->xfn    : '';

            // If item has_children add atts to a.
            if ( $args->has_children && $depth === 0 ) {
                $atts['href'] = ! empty( $item->url ) ? 

$item->url : '';
                // $atts['data-toggle'] = 'dropdown';
                $atts['class']          = 'dropdown-

toggle';
                $atts['aria-haspopup']  = 'true';
            } else {
                $atts['href'] = ! empty( $item->url ) ? 

$item->url : '';
            }

            $atts = apply_filters( 

'nav_menu_link_attributes', $atts, $item, $args );

            $attributes = '';
            foreach ( $atts as $attr => $value ) {
                if ( ! empty( $value ) ) {
                    $value = ( 'href' === $attr ) ? esc_url( 

$value ) : esc_attr( $value );
                    $attributes .= ' ' . $attr . '="' . 

$value . '"';
                }
            }

            $item_output = $args->before;

            /*
             * Glyphicons
             * ===========
             * Since the the menu item is NOT a Divider or 

Header we check the see
             * if there is a value in the attr_title 

property. If the attr_title
             * property is NOT null we apply it as the class 

name for the glyphicon.
             */
            if ( ! empty( $item->attr_title ) )
                $item_output .= '<a'. $attributes .'><span 

class="glyphicon ' . esc_attr( $item->attr_title ) . 

'"></span>&nbsp;';
            else
                $item_output .= '<a'. $attributes .'>';

            $item_output .= $args->link_before . 

apply_filters( 'the_title', $item->title, $item->ID ) . 

$args->link_after;
            $item_output .= ( $args->has_children && 0 === 

$depth ) ? ' <span class="caret"></span></a>' : '</a>';
            $item_output .= $args->after;

            $output .= apply_filters( 

'walker_nav_menu_start_el', $item_output, $item, $depth, 

$args );
        }
    }

    /**
     * Traverse elements to create list from elements.
     *
     * Display one element if the element doesn't have any 

children otherwise,
     * display the element and its children. Will only 

traverse up to the max
     * depth and no ignore elements under that depth.
     *
     * This method shouldn't be called directly, use the 

walk() method instead.
     *
     * @see Walker::start_el()
     * @since 2.5.0
     *
     * @param object $element Data object
     * @param array $children_elements List of elements to 

continue traversing.
     * @param int $max_depth Max depth to traverse.
     * @param int $depth Depth of current element.
     * @param array $args
     * @param string $output Passed by reference. Used to 

append additional content.
     * @return null Null on failure with no changes to 

parameters.
     */
    public function display_element( $element, &

$children_elements, $max_depth, $depth, $args, &$output ) {
        if ( ! $element )
            return;

        $id_field = $this->db_fields['id'];

        // Display this element.
        if ( is_object( $args[0] ) )
            $args[0]->has_children = ! empty( 

$children_elements[ $element->$id_field ] );

        parent::display_element( $element, 

$children_elements, $max_depth, $depth, $args, $output );
    }

    /**
     * Menu Fallback
     * =============
     * If this function is assigned to the wp_nav_menu's 

fallback_cb variable
     * and a manu has not been assigned to the theme location 

in the WordPress
     * menu manager the function with display nothing to a 

non-logged in user,
     * and will add a link to the WordPress menu manager if 

logged in as an admin.
     *
     * @param array $args passed from the wp_nav_menu 

function.
     *
     */
    public static function fallback( $args ) {
        if ( current_user_can( 'manage_options' ) ) {

            extract( $args );

            $fb_output = null;

            if ( $container ) {
                $fb_output = '<' . $container;

                if ( $container_id )
                    $fb_output .= ' id="' . $container_id . 

'"';

                if ( $container_class )
                    $fb_output .= ' class="' . 

$container_class . '"';

                $fb_output .= '>';
            }

            $fb_output .= '<ul';

            if ( $menu_id )
                $fb_output .= ' id="' . $menu_id . '"';

            if ( $menu_class )
                $fb_output .= ' class="' . $menu_class . '"';

            $fb_output .= '>';
            $fb_output .= '<li><a href="' . admin_url( 'nav-

menus.php' ) . '">Add a menu</a></li>';
            $fb_output .= '</ul>';

            if ( $container )
                $fb_output .= '</' . $container . '>';

            echo $fb_output;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: My question is - how to I add a class to the child of a submenu item?

Comment: I am trying to find an answer to this same question myself. Anyone??

Answer (score 5):

You could try this: add this to your styles.css, it's work for me:

```
/* dropdown */
.dropdown-menu {
    margin: 0px auto;
}
.dropdown-menu .dropdown-menu {
    left: 100%;
    top: 0px;
}
/*  shows the dropdown on hover*/
.navbar ul.nav li:hover > ul.dropdown-menu {
    display: block;   
}
/* before and after */
.navbar .nav > li > .dropdown-menu::before, .navbar .nav > li > .dropdown-menu::after {
    display: none;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I used a WordPress custom template made by Bootstrap, and the third level's menu was displayed over the second's menu, and this code helped me to show it next to the second, so now the menu works great on PC, but on toggled sidebar (mobile view) is not the best.

Answer (score 0):

For the solved this problem.follow interaction.....

Add script(function($){ $(document).ready(function(){ $('ul.dropdown-menu [data-toggle=dropdown]').on('click', function(event) { event.preventDefault(); event.stopPropagation(); $(this).parent().siblings().removeClass('open'); $(this).parent().toggleClass('open'); }); }); })(jQuery);

2.Remove && $depth === 0 from this line if ( $args->has_children && $depth === 0 ) in wp_bootstrap_navwalker.php file

[image]